# Trying to add 0.1 in a while loop ends up adding about 0.1

Tags: kotlin

I'm going through the Kotlin Apprentice book and the exercise is:
*Print 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0.*

Below is my original code and the output.  I tried using Float and got a similar problem.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var count = 0.0
    print(count)
    while (count < 1) {
        count += 0.1
        print(", $count")
    }
```

prints out: 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999, 1.0999999999999999

```
var count: Float = 0.0F
    print(count)
    while (count < 1) {
        count += 0.1F
        print(", $count")
    }
```

prints out: 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.70000005, 0.8000001, 0.9000001, 1.0000001

Solution after reviewing reference in comments of answer:

```
var count = 0.0
    print(count)
    while (count < 10) {
        count += 1
        print(", ${count/10}")
    }
```

prints out: 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0

Thank you for the reference, very interesting.

Comment: And if you need to round these to one decimal place to print them as Strings, you can use `String.format()`. In this case, you can replace your `print` line with `print(", %.1f".format(count))`

Comment: Here is a way to modify your original attempt to work:  https://repl.it/repls/IntelligentBeigeDatum